# Create Code 128 Barcodes within Excel

Tags: ms-office, macos

I'm trying to create Code 128 Barcodes within Microsoft Excel.
I have tried all VBA Makros and Fonts I found on Google, but none give's me a scannable result (usually there are weird characters like ó's mixed in).
Does anybody have a working solution?

Comment: Please consider editing your original question instead of asking a slightly different one.

Comment: I thought I'll let the old one remain since the context is different and it seems it has been a non-existing question so far